# show an array of data in windows phone app

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a two-dimensional array:

```
a   b   c   d   f   g   h   i
2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   2   3   2   1   7   8   9
4   3   2   1   5   7   8   9
2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   2   3   2   1   7   8   9
4   3   2   1   5   7   8   9
2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   2   3   2   1   7   8   9
4   3   2   1   5   7   8   9
```

I want to display this array in a WP7 app, so I tried this code:

```
int top = 50;
for (var rows = 0; rows < jsonObject["data"].Count(); rows++)
{
    int left = 0;
    for (var cols = 0; cols < jsonObject["data"][rows].Count(); cols++)
    {
        TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
        txt.FontSize = 21;
        txt.Text = (String)jsonObject["data"][rows][cols];
        Canvas.SetTop(txt, top);
        Canvas.SetLeft(txt, left);
        MainCanvas.Children.Add(txt);
        left = left + 100;
    }
    top = top + 100;
}
```

Each element of the array is shown in a `TextBlock`,

Right now it looks like this:

```
    a   b   c   d   
    2   3   4   5     
    1   2   3   2       /// rest of the columns is invisible 
    4   3   2   1  
    2   3   4   5  
    1   2   3   2  

   /// rest of the rows is invisible
```

The problem is that I cant slide the data left as well as down, so only a limited amount rows & columns are visible to me.

Can anyone give me a possible solution?

Comment: create template and just bind the values to a listbox or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will help (can't test it at the moment), but maybe putting it in a ScrollViewer will help. Something like:

```
var scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer();
scrollViewer.Content = txt;
```

Maybe you'll have to set the width and height or the horizontal/vertical alignment to make the scrollviewer take the necessary screenspace.